# What types should I use for these data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I 'm not sure what type (set, integer, time, char, varchar, text,...) should I use for these data:

- IP
- personal message
- data and time
- title
- name (or surname)
- user-agent
- forum answer (or comment)
- email address
- country
- password
- custom session cookie

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting? Sometimes I'd be glad if our programmers asked this kind of question more often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends a bit on your personal taste/your company's conventions, but I'd use:

- **IP:** CHAR(15)
- **personal message:** TEXT
- **date and time:** DATETIME
- **title:** VARCHAR(255)
- **name (or surname):** VARCHAR(255)
- **user-agent:** VARCHAR(255)
- **forum answer (or comment):** TEXT
- **email address:** VARCHAR(255)
- **country:** CHAR(2)
- **password:** VARCHAR(255)
- **custom session cookie:** VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Why there is no BLOB? phpBB uses BLOB in some places.

Comment: Because all the cases you listed are human-readable text that will benefit from character set conversion. That is the difference between BLOB and TEXT: TEXT will be converted from and to the client's connection character set.

Comment: Password should be at least MD5() encoded, so that is CHAR(32).

Comment: I dislike MD5 for its lack of collision resistance. I can't decide on an alternative, though. ;)

Comment: ip should be `int` which is more efficient, and `text` should be avoided if possible, in this case, i think `personal message` and `forum answer` are not so long that should use `text`

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda funny question, but i will answer for IP address.

You could store IP address in an INT UNSIGNED.

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.0.10') AS ipn; 

mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(3232235530) AS ipa;
```

So you can store an IP address in an INT UNSIGNED (4 bytes) which is of course much more efficient and faster than a CHAR(15).

Comment: If your heading for maximum saving on space, yes. On the other hand it's less practical to view in a client software and even range lookups will possibly be slower.

Comment: Client should select via function INET_NTOA() and correct output IP will be viewed. range lookups are faster, why would it be slower? Example: if you search from which country IP is, this is best solution. http://www.ip2location.com/ has database in INT values.

Comment: No client that I know of (e.g. phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, Navicat, HeidiSQL) can do that when viewing a table. For slow lookups I had in mind something like `WHERE INET_NTOA(col) LIKE "192.168.%.255"`, now I see i didn't state that clear enough.

Comment: There is a possible improvement(?). Store IPs into 4 tinyint columns.

Comment: As a client I meant custom admin or something, no customer will look at phpmyadmin ;-) You are correct if you need the search as you writen. So at the end, you must know what will you do with this IP column. That why this thread is a little funny. And another thing, this is for only IPv4 ip's. Some reading > http://bafford.com/2009/03/09/mysql-performance-benefits-of-storing-integer-ip-addresses/